# Intellij Live Templates seems to be locked. Buttons for new or duplicate are inactive. How do I enable them?

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij Live Templates seems to be locked. Buttons for new or duplicate are inactive. How do I enable them?

I can edit existing but can not easily add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you should check your **Live Template** configuration. press the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> or directly open the preferences and in the search type `live templates` or go the **Edit**>**Live Templates**. you should see the below:

[image]

- Check the `By default expand with` value
- Check the list of live templates

[image]

- Check the checkbox for each file extension you want.

[image]

- Also, check the **Main Menu**>**Code**>**Insert Live Templates**. Check can you see the list of live templates? and Also, check can you same by using shortcut keys. my shortcut keys are <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.